# Code not working when I'm breaking it up into different lines

Tags: syntax, syntax-highlighting, input

The following code works perfectly

```
For[i=1,i<4,i++,Print[i]]
```

However, when I break this into different lines, it stops working. Moreover, the braces appear to be pink or red

```
For
[
i=1,i<4,i++,
Print[i]
]
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: It's possible that your example could have worked under some very old versions of Mathematica, where line breaks tended to be ignored.

Answer (score 6):

This happens because the expression

```
For
```

is complete at the location of the newline. Mathematica will not attempt to read further. Instead, it will try to interpret the next line as the start of a new expression.

Compare this with

```
For[
```

which is incomplete at the newline. Mathematica will read further to try to complete it.

Thus, use

```
For[
  i=1, i<4, i++,
  Print[i]
]
```